# Angular - Inject/pass service to external library

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm working on a NPM package to provide extra functionalities to the Material Datatable. One of those feature is the possibility to pass a method that will be executed when the user clicks on a specific cell.

Here is the definition of the property:

#### Inside external library

```
click?: (element: any, property: string, event: MouseEvent) => unknown = null;
```

Passing a simple method to it, like an alert or a console.log works fine:

#### From the project using the library

```
{
    click: this.alert
}

...

alert(element: any, property: string, mouseEvent: MouseEvent) {
    alert(element[property]);
}
```

However, if I pass a method that contains a call to a service, the library knows nothing about that service and the method crashes:

```
{
    click: this.openDialog
}

...

openDialog(element: any, property: string, mouseEvent: MouseEvent) {
    this.matDialog.open(DialogComponent);
}
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

How could I dynamically provide any type of service to an external library ? And how will the library know which service to use ?

Or maybe I'm going in the wrong direction ? I did tried to simply use an event emitter and pass the value to the parent component, but it has limitations (called on every cells, extra logic needed in the parent)

Comment: not sure, try `click: this.openDialog.bind(this)`. Could be possible that your this is the wrong this if you understand what i mean

Comment: haha, yes, I understand what you mean. And your trick worked, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. One, it doesn't know about the type because you're not parameterizing your `click` handler (check out [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)). Two, you're using a normal function definition that is implicitly binding context where it's being invoked. So if your external library is firing `click` and `this.openDialog` is associated with that, essentially the library is going to be looking for `this.matDialog.open(DialogComponent);` inside of itself (which it will not find, thus the undefined).

I would suggest trying this:

```
{
    click: this.openDialog.bind(this)
}

...

openDialog(element: any, property: string, mouseEvent: MouseEvent) {
    this.matDialog.open(DialogComponent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! First time I see this `bind` syntax, pretty useful

Comment: @Robouste Yeah, context in JavaScript can be confusing, the gist though is:

Normal function = bind at execution

Arrow function = bind at definition

There's more that goes into this, but that should help.